# Codeigniter: How to update an amount that will not affect a specific columns

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, model

Hi guys I have a problem in my query in model, I'll show you the code before I explain it.

```
for($x = 1; $x <= count($this->input->post('subparticulars')); $x++) {

   $feetype = $this->input->post('subparticulars')[$x];
   $student = $this->input->post('substudentid');
   $schoolyear = $this->input->post('subschoolyeardata');
   $month = $this->input->post('month');

   $payment = $this->input->post('subpaymentamount')[$x];

   $this->db->set('statement_amount', '`statement_amount` -'. $payment, FALSE);

   $this->db->where(array('feetype_id !=' => 2, 'feetype_id !=' => 3, 'feetype_id' => $feetype, 'student_id' => $student, 'schoolyear_id' => $schoolyear, 'month_id' => $month));

   $status3 = $this->db->update('tbl_statement');
 }
```

Here I have an add dynamic add row function which has contains the amounts and particulars of multiple payment in subparticulars and subpayments, I'm running a query that will minus my payments in my statement_amounts, as you can see in the $this->db->set. Now, I have a problem with my where clause, if you will try to understand my where clause this is the conditions.

I want to update all my fees except the one that has the feetype_id: 2 and 3, but the other feetype_id will be updated, How can I achieve this. When I'm running the code it still subtracts the fees that have feetype_id of 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct answer

```
for($x = 1; $x <= count($this->input->post('subparticulars')); $x++) {

   $feetype = $this->input->post('subparticulars')[$x];
   $student = $this->input->post('substudentid');
   $schoolyear = $this->input->post('subschoolyeardata');
   $month = $this->input->post('month');

   $payment = $this->input->post('subpaymentamount')[$x];

   if ($feetype == 2 OR $feetype == 3)
   {
      $this->db->set('statement_amount', '`statement_amount` -'. $payment, FALSE);

      $this->db->where(array('feetype_id' => $feetype, 'student_id' => $student, 'schoolyear_id' => $schoolyear));

      $status3 = $this->db->update('tbl_statement');
   }        
   else {
      $this->db->set('statement_amount', '`statement_amount` -'. $payment, FALSE);

      $this->db->where(array('feetype_id' => $feetype, 'student_id' => $student, 'schoolyear_id' => $schoolyear, 'month_id' => $month));

      $status3 = $this->db->update('tbl_statement');
   }     
 }
```